Royer Oscillator part of Transmitter circuit of Wireless Charger
Could you please help me to make calculation for this circuit because i did it but i didnt get the correct result in simulation in LT SPICE.[


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

HOW i measure the output voltage in this circuit in LT SPICE to get a good result

The question is how to measure? Have you read the LTspice documentation? Or the question is how to simulate the circuit at all, or how to improve it?

@T1991 - Hi, You wrote this new question (containing the LTspice schematic for the circuit here), instead of adding it to this question. That question clearly overlaps this one and should not have been asked separately, since any analysis on that question would be relevant to this one too. || Please [edit] & improve this question, add your LTspice simulation (& ideally its netlist) here, show your simulation results and the calculations which (you said) don't match the simulation. Clarify what you are requesting as an answer. TY

Note that L1 and L2 should be coupled in opposition ...

Update : modified circuit (verifying Vgates)


What are the gate voltages?

Exact ... I did not check. Too high.

i want first the calculation of the circuit what i should get in transmitter coil the output voltage

The input source is DC 15V

Why you put schottcky diode with resistor

To limit Vgs on the 2 MOSFET's. Vgs is too high (almost 30 V > 20 V) without these Zener ~ 15V.

@T1991 Note that the circuit is now changed ... 4x 1N4148 should not be used to make a wireless charger  ...

So what diode should be used

you must choose diodes with some current (something as 3 A mean 1N5402 or similar).
